# Determine the convergence and the limit of $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ when n$\rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$   \ $\{0\}$:
$\begin{cases}
u_1=a\\
u_{n+1}=\frac{{u_n}^2}{u_n+v_n}.
\end{cases}$
$\begin{cases}
v_1=b\\
v_{n+1}=\frac{{v_n}^2}{u_n+v_n}.
\end{cases}$

a) Calculate the limit when n tends to infinity of both sequences when $a=b$
b) If $|a|<|b|$ prove that both converges and calculate both limits

This question was asked to me by a friend that is trying to be a high school teacher on math.
This is my last try on a) part of the problem: If $a=b$ then we can show by induction that $u_n=v_n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So $(u_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=(v_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=(\frac{a}{2^n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ wich limit as n tends to infinity is $0$ ($a\neq 0$).
I think the b) part has something to do with this reasoning but i can not see a clear way of tackling it. Could someone help me?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$u_{n+1} - v_{n+1} = \frac{u_n^2 -v_n^2}{u_n + v_n } = u_n - v_n =u_{n-1} - v_{n-1}=...=u_1 -v_1 = a-b \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{v_{n+1}} = \left(\frac{u_n}{v_n}  \right)^2=...= \left(\frac{u_1}{v_1}  \right)^{2^n}= \left(\frac{a}{b}  \right)^{2^n} \tag{2}$$

From $(1),(2)$, we deduce easily that
$$v_n = \frac{a-b}{\left(\frac{a}{b}  \right)^{2^{n-1}}-1}$$
and
$$u_n = \left(\frac{a}{b}  \right)^{2^{n-1}} v_n = \left(\frac{a}{b}  \right)^{2^{n-1}}\cdot \frac{a-b}{\left(\frac{a}{b}  \right)^{2^{n-1}}-1}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, it is a really nice proof!!